# MongoDB Aggregation - elemMatch for all subobjects

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

There is the following array of strings:

```
categoryExclusions = ["2"];
```

And the following mongodb collection structure:

```
[
    {
        "myItems": [
            {
                "_id": "xxx",
                "name": "just a name 1",
                "category": [
                    "1"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": "yyy",
                "name": "just a name 2",
                "category": [
                    "2"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "_id": "zzz",
        "name": "Parent Name",
    },

    {
    // another parent object
    },

    {
    // another parent object
    },

    etc.
]
```

I would like to return the documents that do not contain in any of their myItems categories an element of categoryExclusions and I am applying the following code:

```
          $match: {
            "myItems.category": {
              $elemMatch: {
                $nin: categoryExclusions,
              },
            },
          }
```

But the problem is that the condition is not met for category: ["1"] which makes the query return the entire first parent object. The expected output should be no object as categoryExclusions contains a string that exists in one of the categories of the myItems field.

I believe this behaviour is happening because of elemMatch which returns the documents if the condition is met at least for one of the category fields of myItems, but I tried using $all and other operators with no success. Can somebody please help me with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
      $match: {
        "myItems.category": {$not: {
          $elemMatch: {
            $in: categoryExclusions,
          },
        }},
      }
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems like it's working... could you please explain why?

Comment: It is a straightforward expression of "documents that do not contain in any of their myItems categories an element of categoryExclusions "